# How is this an object {handler, context}?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am looking at code that says:

```
const listen = {handler, context}
```

Where:  `handler` is a function and `context` is unknown.

The code runs and when I run `typeof listen` I get an object from a debugger but I don't see how this is an object. The notation of an object literal is `{prop: propValue}`.

What am I missing about objects?

Comment: It's a shorthand introduced in ES2015. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: specifically, shorthand for `const listen = {handler:handler, context:context}`

Comment: It is because you are creating a constant variable with predefined variables that do not need to be initialized in the object itself. this: `const object = { a: 'foo', b: 42, c: {} };` is the same as this: `var a = 'foo'; var b = 42; var c = {}; const object = {a,b,c}`

Comment: Thanks. could any of you provide an answer so that I can upvote there as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following:

```
const listen = {handler, context}
```

Is just shorthand for :

```
const listen = {handler: handler, context: context}
```

## More

These are known as `shorthand property names` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer